# Adding week number and week ranges of a year to DropDown List in ASP.NET3.5 using JQUERY

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am learning jQuery. Here I have a requirement i.e I have to add Week number and Week ranges of a year to DropDown List in ASP.NET3.5. And I have to pass selected week range to database. I am using c#.net. This should be done automatically for every year.

How can I do this using JQUERY?

Regards,

JN

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 function getDateRangeOfWeek(weekNo){

      var d1 = new Date();

      numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday = eval(d1.getDay()- 1);

      d1.setDate(d1.getDate() - numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday);

      var weekNoToday = d1.getWeek();

      var weeksInTheFuture = eval( weekNo - weekNoToday );

      d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + eval( 7 * weeksInTheFuture ));

      var rangeIsFrom = eval(d1.getMonth()+1) +"/" + d1.getDate() + "/" + d1.getFullYear();

      d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 6);

      var rangeIsTo = eval(d1.getMonth()+1) +"/" + d1.getDate() + "/" + d1.getFullYear() ;

      return rangeIsFrom + " to "+rangeIsTo;

      };
```

answer is originally from

http://snipplr.com/view/7540/get-date-range-from-week-number-in-year/